# What synchronization model does SVN use?

Tags: svn

There are a few synchronization models according to Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_model

CVS uses the first one, check-in/check-out, but is that what SVN uses? I know Mercurial/Git use the change set model, but what does SVN use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion uses ChangeSets to store the information in the repository.

Comment: If you take a look into the repository you will find a file for every revision (ChangeSet) which is stored and for the revision properties but not for a single file.